# need help "hacking" LED display

Tags: microcontroller, led, embedded, 8051

The display is a scrolling LED sign which looks like this:

[image]

It is also distributed in the US by [Grandwell (SLC16H-IR)](http://www.grandwell.com/indoor_single_line.php). The messaging software that it comes with does not allow full control of the sign (On/Off, display different files, ect). It comes with a remote control that can do these functions, but I want to use it for an embedded application and this just won't do.

If anyone knows how to dump the Flash memory on this processor, [SyncMOS SM89516A](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/syncmos/sm89516a.pdf), then I can add some function calls to the software and get the control that I want (for the price I want). Any ideas? I'm exploring the [MSM9042 ISP Download Board](http://www.syncmos.com.tw/technical.php?language=english&pid=3#) from the SyncMOS website, which may or may not work.

Comment: Interesting problem!  Have you considered reverse engineering the remote control's protocol?

Comment: I've tossed the thought around. The remote goes into a different pin; I scoped the signal and it seems possible. Unfortunately, to open a file it has a prompt that says "Run?=_ _" (or something like that). I want it to open the file without a prompt.

Comment: I thought you were going to dump the remote and that whole input system and build a device to replace it. Anything appears on the display should be irrelevant; your device would emulate the remote and automatically complete the open file prompt.

Answer (score 4):

My first idea is that hacking the software may require more work than building a display from scratch. You could cannibalize the display itself and connect your own controller to it.

If you want to do it with the SM89516A, it appears to have a 8051 core, but on the pinout I can't see any special pins for programming. It probably uses a pair of I/O pins like UART to communicate with the programmer. There's no standard for this, I've already seen different protocols for it, which means you're out of luck if you can't find it documented in some SyncMOS document.
You may have to disconnect the programming pins because they may be used for other functions. This could mean patching the PCB as well.
I would go for a new controller. The interface will be simple if you use the existing display as a module.

Looking at the documents on the SyncMOS website, they don't look very encouraging. Application note for programming is an animated GIF(!), showing how to program the device on a Hi-Lo programmer. Nothing wrong with Hi-Lo, but I tend to stay away as far as possible from companies which don't manage to create better documents.
The Hi-Lo also suggest that the programming protocol may be somewhat involved.

Comment: I've heard alot of people say that... It SHOULDN'T be more work, why does everyone keep saying that? Their program can do everything I want (ie, the subroutines exist), but it doesn't let me do those functions from the serial port. Theoretically, I should be able to add some commands that will jump into the right subroutines, then I don't have to spend all the extra time (and cost) to design/test/manufacture a new controller board.

Comment: @Andy - wait a minute! You don't want to add functionality? only control it from EIA-232 instead of the (IR?) remote control? In that case I would leave the display untouched, and program a microcontroller which takes the EIA-232 commands as input and retransmits them to the existing remote control receiver.